# SQL hierarchyid on employee table with inactive records (multiple root nodes)

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

For those using a SQL hierarchyid for an employee table, how do you accomodate inactive (retired, terminated) employee records contained on the same table? In the case of a new CEO (root) this leads to several rows that have a NULL parentID. Is it common practice to migrate those records to a separate table?

We have an employee table that has both active and inactive records. This is useful for many of the downstream systems that use employee data but are slow to update their own related data after an employee leaves. For example, a project system that uses the employee table to track the project manager. If those systems were to refer to a table that only had active employees they would not find matching rows when pulling employee data.

**Clarification on question**
To clarify the question, I have read articles on multiple roots and I realize that is possible. My question is more about how this is dealt with in the field. As stated, one option is to have inactive records could be moved to a separate table so the root node is always a single CEO. Another option might be a dummy root for "org" followed by all the CEO records (past and present). Or you can skip the "/" root altogether and just start with all the CEO records. I assume this scenario (employee table with active/inactive CEO type records) is common so I wanted to hear what solutions are being used.

**Update on source data**
FYI - The source employee table is upstream from my system and we get updates from an Active Directory feed. I cannot switch the source to eliminate the child_id / parent_id columns. I can however update our copy to include hierarchyid for the apps downstream from us. I would keep the child_id / parent_id in our data so I could use the feed to update our copy.

Comment: Don't see what an employee's status has to do with changing the root of a hierarchy. They should be two different fields because they deal with different concerns. Moving a subtree from one node to another (or one root to another) isn't anything weird, it's even mentioned in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx#BKMK_MovingSubtrees). Finally, when you use a `HierarchyId` type there's no need for a `ParentID` field at all.

Comment: I have not explored the logic for hierarchyid maintenance yet but from an inial load point of view having multiple children with NULL parents would seem to be an issue. Typically the root in an employee hierarchy is the child that has no parent. For a table of active employees this works as the root will be a single CEO. If the table contains both current and past CEOs then you have several children with no parent who could be considered the root.

Comment: You assume there can be only one tree per table. That's not correct. There's no requirement that the hierarchy field is unique, nor that there is only one tree per table. Nothing prevents you from having multiple trees, nor is it a mistake to have multiple trees. Assuming that the root is active on the other hand is a mistake as you use one field to convey two independent types of information. You do need to understand how the HierarchyID type works and how subtrees can be moved before starting to think about nulls and restructuring

Comment: If you allow hierarchyid to not be unique don't you allow the possibility for a violation on a child only having a single parent? If you allow multiple /3/2 values then who is the parent of /3/2/1? I have read the articles on mulitple trees and most point out that while it is possible it is not the most desired solution. My assumption is that this scenario (employee table with inactive roots) is not uncommon so I wanted to know how others dealt with it in the field. I'll try to clarify the question a bit with an update.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this and maintain the historical hierarchy is to include a Start & End Date for each relationship. So there are 5 VPs reporting to CEO John, and John is leaving next month. When new CEO Dave come in, these 5 VPs will report to Dave instead. You don't need to change the whole hierarchy.

Another approach is a few fixed title at the top, and simply update the CEO's name from John to Dave (I don't recommend this though but I have seen it being used).